# Как в один объект добавить либо переопределить свойства из другого объекта?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Есть два некоторых неизвестных объекта. Их нужно соединить в один. При чем необходимо соединить по правилам:

- если в объекте `a` и в объекте `b` присутствует одинаковый объект (либо подобъект **ЛЮБОЙ** вложенности), то оставить объект из `b`;
- если в объекте `a` и в объекте `b` присутствует одинаковый объект и он является **массивом**, то надо соединить оба этих массива;
- если в объекте `b` есть объект, отсутствующий в `a`, то добавить его.
- Надо либо изменить `a`, либо получить новый объект.

Приведу пример:

```
a: {
  car: "WW",
  detail:{
    wheel: {
      left: "good",
      right:"bad"
    }
  },
  props: [
    {prop1: "1"},
    {prop1: "2"},
    {prop1: "3"}
  ]
};
// Теперь объект b, который надо совместить:
b: {
  detail:{
    wheel: {
      left: "bad",//изменяем свойство из a на это
      center: "good"//появилось новое свойство
    }
  }
  props: [
    {prop1: "4"}//Добавляем в массив к a.
  ]
}
//вот что получиться должно:
c: {
  car: "WW",
  detail:{
    wheel: {
      left: "bad",
      right:"bad",
      center: "good"
    }
  },
  props: [
    {prop1: "1"},
    {prop1: "2"},
    {prop1: "3"},
    {prop1: "4"}
  ]
};
```

**PS**:
Без использования каких-либо библиотек.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так?

```
function extend(a, b){
    for(var prop in b){
        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(b[prop]) == '[object Array]' &&
           Object.prototype.toString.call(a[prop]) == '[object Array]'){ // is array?
                a[prop] = a[prop].concat(b[prop]);
        } else { 
            if(b[prop] === Object(b[prop]) && 
               a[prop] === Object(a[prop])){ // is object?
                extend(a[prop], b[prop]);
            } 
            else {            
                a[prop] = b[prop];
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:** исправил некорректную работу с массивами.

Comment: Выглядит красиво, и, вроде, что надо. Ща попробую!

Comment: .

     Object.prototype.toString.call(b[prop]) == '[object Array]'
     // ну лучше ли
     b[prop].constructor === Array // ?

К тому-же, если вообще по православному, то лучше всего сделать как-то так:

    if(!Array.isArray) {
     Array.isArray = function( v ){
      return v && v.constructor === Array
     } 
    }

Ну и дальше в коде: (кэп)

    Array.isArray( b[prop] );

    // ну и, на мой взгляд, вместо
    b[prop] === Object(b[prop])

    // все-же приятнее смотрится конструкция вида
    b[prop].constructor === Object

Comment: хз, вообще уже существует `Array.isArray`

на счёт `b[prop].constructor === Object` 

var func = function(){
    this.name = 'name';
}
var obj = new func();
obj.constructor === Object; //fulse

Comment: ({fd:"qwe"} === Object({fd:"qwe"})) -- получится false, всегда. Но в общем идея мне ясна, спасибо. Ответ принимаю.

Comment: А, вы исправили ответ. Так вообще хорошо. Спасибо!

Comment: @Spectre именно для этого я и предлагаю так писать, таким образом мы используем стандартную реализацию (если она доступна, а если говорить о браузерах "еретиках", то там ее, естественно - нет), если нет, то используем кастомный код, кстати развивая мысль, точно такую-же функцию можно написать и для Object, String, etc.

Comment: я привык в таких случаях полагаться на [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-99)

Comment: @Spectre это тоже вариант, но в приведенном вами примере вы его не использовали :)

По поводу вашего примера - если объект не является "чистым", то, как минимум, не стоит писать так много буков

      var obj = new func();
      toString.call( obj ); // -> [object Object]

Comment: я подумал, что тащить целую библиотеку ради 2-х функций - это слишком=) хотя многие тащат в проекты `jQuery` только ради `$.ajax`

Comment: @Spectre - вы абсолютно правы, это слишком. Да и, вашего решения, я не критикую, всего-лишь предлагаю варианты более красивой записи, не более.

Answer (score -3):

Если с jQuery, то все просто

```
$.extend(true, obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: _PS:
Без использования каких-либо библиотек._, и еще дополнительно проверьте как отработает extend в случае с массивами и как требуется автору